# How should coreference resolution be handled for possessive pronouns?

Tags: anaphora

When dealing with coreference resolution, what is the correct way to handle a possessive pronoun followed by another noun? Consider:

**Alice has a cousin called Bob.**
**Alice went to visit her cousin.**

In the second sentence, I can see three potential ways to resolve *her cousin*:

1. *her* refers to Alice.
2. *her* refers to Alice and *cousin* refers to Bob.
3. *her cousin* refers to Bob.

In the literature I have found examples of both 1 and 3, so it is unclear which is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 and 3 are not mutually exclusive, and they are both correct.  2 is not possible, because "cousin" is a noun, not a NP, and only NPs refer, not nouns.  Nouns predicate, they don't refer (unless they are also NPs).